# Updating BlueCard address mid-application

Tags: germany, immigration, blue-card

I have an appointment at the Berlin immigration office for a BlueCard this month.

I have provided my current apartment's address for the BlueCard application. But my current apartment's lease ends in 3 months and I will have to move into another place.

Assuming it takes 4 to 6 months for the BlueCard to arrive, what happens if my address gets changed in the meanwhile?

Will my BlueCard be sent to the old address and then returned since the doorbell and letter-box wont have my name?

Can I somehow intimate the foreigner's office about the address change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An Aufenthaltstitel won't be sent per post, but must be picked up.

Comment: Sorry but I have heard from more than one person who have recently received their Residence Permits that it was sent by post!

Comment: Since you have an appointment, ask. Also ask if it can be picked up at the Bürgerbüro (which seems now to often to be the case). When you move, you must register your new address at the Bürgerbüro. They will then know your new address. [elektronischer Aufenthaltstitel (eAT) - Ausgabe am Standort LEA, Friedrich-Krause-Ufer - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326231/standort/121885/) (translated): **Collection in person or by an authorized person** It is not common for such documents to be sent per post and nothing anywhere says that it will be.

Comment: Thanks @MarkJohnson!